# Python calling two functions by clicking one button in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am new to Python. I have created a button using PyQt and want to call two separate functions by clicking the same button

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.start, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.trial,self.trial2)
```

Comment: What about putting both functions into a new single function with is excecuted by the button?

Comment: But I want both the function to start at the same time.

Comment: Why do they have to start at the same time ?

Comment: I want both the functions to take the same input from the user and display the output at the same time

Comment: why is it not one function ?

Comment: If i'll put the second function in the first one then they will not execute simultaneously. But I want them to execute in parallel

Comment: I think you should edit your question with the two functions. It's hard to give advice without knowing exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 11):

You can just connect the signal twice, like:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.start, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.trial)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.start, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.trial2)
```

Both functions will be called when the signal is emitted. According to the document:

> If a signal is connected to several slots, the slots are activated in the same order in which the connections were made, when the signal is emitted.

Comment: I wanted both the functions to start at the same time. Will this work ?

Comment: @user2693313 See my edit. If you want to start them at the same (almost) time, you may want to start a new thread to do the job in the slot.

Comment: @user2693313: Without talking about [multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Multithreading) or [multiprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing), your computer is not able to do things at the same time or in parallel. But depending on what you want to do this does not matter since processing in serial should be fast and feeling like in parallel for normal usage.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to do that ?

Comment: This is kind of rather difficult. First of all think about whether you really need to do things in parallel. Could you please tell us what you want you intend to do? What is your aim?

Comment: I want both the functions to take the same input from the user and display the output at the same time

Comment: In this case serial processing should do the job. There should not be any noticeable delay between both outputs. I do not know how this is done in qt, but there might by something like an `update` method which you could call to refresh your widgets after passing the desired output to them in order to seperate widget / data handling and output to the user.

Comment: I am using PyQT just to create the UI.